# UCM search - integration with .net

Tags: .net, search, soap, wsdl, oracle-ucm

I have integrated my web app with oracle ucm through building service refrences for the exposed wsdls from ucm.

I have been trying to call either QuickSearch and AdvancedSearch methods available on search service. The strange thing is that it does work, but the result is always the same regardless of what search query or extra properties I set, I am getting back all documents available in ucm as result. My code goes something like this:

```
IdcProperty extra = new IdcProperty();
extra.name = "dID";
extra.value = "210";
IdcProperty[] array = {extra};
QuickSearchRequest search = new QuickSearchRequest(searchWord, array);
QuickSearchResponse res =  proxy.QuickSearch(search);
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if any one is looking for this. Turns out you don't just send the search word as is, it needs to be formatted this way

```
string searhword = String.Format("<usch>dDocTitle <substring> `{0}`</usch>", "obama");
```

You might also consider using AdvancedSearch instead of quick search. Search seems to be case sensitive, I guess this can be changed on UCM side. You should also open this link on the UCM "/cs/idcplg?IdcService=GET_PORTAL_PAGE&Action=GetTemplatePage&Page=TARGETED_QUICK_SEARCH_LIST" to check how to send other type of queries